# Elasticsearch Per-Field Boosts, Wildcard and Explicit Field Matches Conflict

Tags: elasticsearch

Some queries in Elasticsearch offer wildcard matching for fields with boosts, for example, the [`simple_query_string query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#simple-query-string-boost).
In our use-case we would like to boost specific fields while giving all other fields a score of 0. We thought this could be achieved with the following example query pattern:

```
GET /kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
  "profile": "true",
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "Eddie",
      "fields": [
        "*^0",
        "customer_full_name^100"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It appears though that if several field definitions match the same field name via wildcards their boosts are **multiplied**. The above example will yield a score of 0 for all documents even if they contain the token "Eddie" in the `customer_full_name` field.

This following example demonstrates that the boosts are multiplied:

```
GET /kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
  "profile": "true",
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "Eddie",
      "fields": [
        "*^0.1",
        "customer_full_name^100"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It leads to the expression `(customer_full_name:eddie)^10.0` in the profile explanation of the query.

Does that mean that it is not possible to achieve our desired outcome with field boosts? The desired outcome is: All matches in a specific field have theirs score multiplied by 100 while all documents with matches in other fields are still returned but have 0 score.

Comment: In the logic of Elasticsearch, i guess a score of `0` means it's not a hit at all.

Comment: Have you tried using a boolean query with two separate `simple_query_string` queries with single fields?

Comment: Score 0 doesn't mean that it's not a hit in this context, documents with no machting terms wouldn't be returned at all.
Thanks for the idea with the boolean query wrapping, it's a workaround that is possible in our use case. :-)

Comment: No, not in this context. But I wanted to say that giving something a boost of `0` might not have been intended my the devs for this very reason :) I'm glad I could give an impulse for a workaround, though.